# How to set a callback when WebView has rendered data (is ready to be displayed)

Tags: android

I use WebView in a dialog and at the first launch it takes up to 1 second to render very simple content. The content is set from code as a String (no loading from network). At the beginning for a while I see empty dialog and then the content appears. How to set a callback for the moment when WebView is ready to be displayed and then call show on an AlertDialogBuilder? I have tried WebViewClient.onPageFinished, WebViewClient.PictureListener.onNewPicture, WebChromeClient.onProgressChanged (==100) with no effect.

Comment: Please define "with no effect". `onPageFinished()` should be the right answer.

Comment: @CommonsWare it means that it does not work for this issue.

Comment: btw onPageFinished is triggered when page is loaded not rendered...

Answer (score 1):

```
webViewInstance.setPictureListener(new PictureListener() {      
   @Override
   public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture) {
      // the code goes here
   }
});
```

Comment: onNewPicture is [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449210/what-does-this-method-is-deprecated-mean-for-application-developers).

Comment: Yeah, but is there any alternative to PictureListener in API 12> ?