# Code fragments are being struck out in Eclipse, why?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

While I'm making an Android app, Eclipse will strike out some things. More specifically, `Gallery`. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

When I hover my mouse over the warnings, it says `The type Gallery is deprecated`. I don't know what `Deprecated` means, but I do know that it's a Java term. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "This method is deprecated" mean for application developers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449210/what-does-this-method-is-deprecated-mean-for-application-developers)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(From the question before editing: The term is deprecated, not depreciated. It's a common typo, but worth being aware of for searching purposes :)

It's basically a bit like "obsolete" - you're encouraged not to use classes or methods which are deprecated. Typically the documentation will explain *why* you're not meant to use them, and give you a better alternative. The deprecated version is only present for backward compatibility, usually.

It's worth taking this seriously - a lot of the time if you're using a deprecated API, you're coming at something from a fundamentally flawed approach. [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is the clearest example of this, where the Java 1.0 API was almost entirely deprecated in 1.1, when [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) was introduced. Using the deprecated methods in `Date` is a sure way of storing up problems for yourself.

See the Oracle ["How and when to deprecate APIs"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html) page for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Deprecated means it used to support older SDK, but not anymore. Thats why you get the warning.

It is just a warning most of the times it works, but you most be careful because it could cause problem with newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

Deprecated isn't a Java term. It is used in many other things but a lot in programming. It simply means that it is no longer supported...normally replaced with something else. The [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) will help you adapt it to what you need depending on what you're doing