# VS Code warns on `super(props);` when extending from React.Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My vscode is warning on `super(props)`,
Anyone has ideas why?

[image]

```
class TableSizeInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
      default_columns: this.props.default_columns,
      default_rows: this.props.default_rows
    };
  };
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "This method is deprecated" mean for application developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449210/what-does-this-method-is-deprecated-mean-for-application-developers) Yes, I know it's for java, but the principle of deprecation is the same ...

Comment: Are you using the feature that's been deprecated, found at the link it provides? https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html

Comment: @zcoop98 yes I think I used a legacy context, thank you

Comment: For what it's worth, VS Code *just* added highlighting of deprecated API usages. More detail here: [VS Code Update August 2020 (version 1.49), Deprecated tag support for JavaScript and TypeScript](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_49#_deprecated-tag-support-for-javascript-and-typescript).

Comment: Had a same issue and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63857001/13160606)